# Creating web application/site collection sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, error, web-application, dns, connection

I've just set up Sharepoint 2013 and I can access this site and the central administration. I'm trying to make another Web Application, but cannot access this page. I'm not sure if this is the problem, I named my Host Header: Intranet.companyname.com. When I went to add the host on the DNS I added it under our current DNS location which is named: companynameops.companyname.local. So, when I added the host I added Intranet and the rest is filled in with companynameops.companyname.local. This leaves the FQDN as Intranet.companynameops.companyname.local. Is this my problem? Also, if I go to Designer to open it only shows me the central admin and my default site, it does not show the new Web Application that I created.

Comment: What error you are getting? Did you point your DNS to sharepoint server?

Comment: I'm getting This page can’t be displayed. Is the problem because the FQDN in DNS is different than the URL name that I made in SharePoint? I'm thinking I need to make an alias in DNS so that it points to the right name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to check

- When you create the DNS record then make sure it is pointing to correct SharePoint server
- Update the AAM setting with the correct URL
- also check the IIS bindings.

**Note:**
When you create new web application then Use the exact the same FQDN as you created in DNS. Also Make Sure the AAM also reflecting the same FQDN there.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48619/discussion-on-answer-by-waqas-sarwar-mcse-creating-web-application-site-collecti).